# How to output per-class accuracy in Keras？

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Caffe can not only print overall accuracy, but also per-class accuracy.

In Keras log, there's only overall accuracy. It's hard for me to calculate the separate class accuracy.

```
Epoch 168/200

0s - loss: 0.0495 - acc: 0.9818 - val_loss: 0.0519 - val_acc: 0.9796

Epoch 169/200

0s - loss: 0.0519 - acc: 0.9796 - val_loss: 0.0496 - val_acc: 0.9815

Epoch 170/200

0s - loss: 0.0496 - acc: 0.9815 - val_loss: 0.0514 - val_acc: 0.9801
```

Anybody who knows how to output per-class accuracy in keras?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Precision & recall are more useful measures for multi-class classification (see [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix)). Following the Keras [MNIST CNN](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py) example (10-class classification), you can get the per-class measures using `classification_report` from [sklearn.metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html#sklearn.metrics.classification_report):

```python
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import numpy as np

Y_test = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1) # Convert one-hot to index
y_pred = model.predict_classes(x_test)
print(classification_report(Y_test, y_pred))
```

Here is the result:

```python
         precision    recall  f1-score   support

      0       0.99      1.00      1.00       980
      1       0.99      0.99      0.99      1135
      2       1.00      0.99      0.99      1032
      3       0.99      0.99      0.99      1010
      4       0.98      1.00      0.99       982
      5       0.99      0.99      0.99       892
      6       1.00      0.99      0.99       958
      7       0.97      1.00      0.99      1028
      8       0.99      0.99      0.99       974
      9       0.99      0.98      0.99      1009

avg / total   0.99      0.99      0.99     10000
```

Comment: @desertnaut.Thanks a lot, This is very usefull for me. This code can output the per-class accuracy in the test time, but how to print  the per-class accuracy in the trainning process in Keras?

Comment: For how many classes? You would really like to print ~ 20 numbers per training epoch??

Comment: @desertnaut.Two classes per trainning epoch. I found some code here:[link]https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/53e541f7bf55de036f4f5641bd2947b96dd8c4c3/keras/metrics.py, but It also prints the over  precision and recall ,not the per-class. And I'm not sure this code will work  correctly when trainning on batch.

Comment: For 2 classes (binary classification) the accuracy is the **same** for both classes! Check the definition...

Comment: @desertnaut I don't understand... my case is that number of objects in each classification are extremely unbalanced, even though it is a `true/false` classification, I don't think the accuracy of both classes are the same.

Comment: @LYu It is - look up the definition of (binary case) accuracy; the only difference in imbalanced cases is that accuracy is no longer very useful, since it can be high by naively classifying everything to the majority class. For more details, pls open a new question.

Comment: The above function returns a whole string. Is there a way to get them as structured data that I can later convert to JSON?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai you are right, it's a [string](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html); haven't thought much about converting it into JSON...

Comment: @desertnaut **Not same** for both classes; a batch (e.g. size 32) can have 4 samples = '1', 28 = '0'; one class's accuracy being 100% or 25% says nothing about the other's.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I kindly suggest you revisit the definition of accuracy, because you sound confused. There is no such thing as "100% accuracy for one class" - 100% accuracy means correctly predicting the class for **all** samples; truth is, in class imbalance settings (such as the one you imply here) accuracy is no longer useful, but this does not mean that its definition changes.

Comment: @desertnaut OP inquired about per-class accuracy - which has only one definition: `(# of samples in class predicted correctly) / (total # of samples in class)`. -- This metric _is_ useful; for binary classification, an accuracy of ~1 for '0' and ~0 for '1' is indicative of the model blindly guessing the majority class to be 'safe', and failing to learn any real features -- to name one example.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon you are still confusing things: this is the **exact** definition of **recall**, or [true positive rate (TPR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity), and **not** of accuracy; again, the fact that accuracy is not *useful* in imbalanced settings does not mean that its definition changes in such cases, which is always `(# of correctly classified samples) / (total # of samples)`. In fact, OP asked for something that does not exist (a fact that was already implied in my answer).

Comment: @desertnaut Quickly realized this after posting; what OP and I call "per-class accuracy" happens to exactly be per-class TPR. In my application, I've fed samples from one class at a time, with Keras returning 'accuracy', so there was a need to _separate_ results for logging/averaging purposes - hence 'per class'. -- So we're both right on the idea, but you are correct on the 'formal' wording.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon understood, but terminology (and not wording) has its own importance, and it is not just a formality. And again, the per-class precision & recall in a multi-class setting is exactly what I have provided in my answer, so it is unclear what more is offered by your own one...

Comment: @desertnaut agreed @importance, but this case's rather involved in that both Keras `.train` and theory definition of "accuracy" is intended. My solution spares an import, and shows a way to store separate class metrics averaged over >1 train updates - but more importantly, how to get per-class metrics _during training_.

Answer (score 7):

You are probably looking to use a callback, which you can easily add to the `model.fit()` call.

For example, you can define your own class using the `keras.callbacks.Callback` interface. I recommend using the `on_epoch_end()` function since it will format nicely inside of your training summary if you decide to print with that verbosity setting. Please note that this particular code block is set to use 3 classes, but you can of course change it to your desired number.

```
# your class labels
classes = ["class_1","class_2", "class_3"]

class AccuracyCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def __init__(self, test_data):
        self.test_data = test_data

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        x_data, y_data = self.test_data

        correct = 0
        incorrect = 0

        x_result = self.model.predict(x_data, verbose=0)

        x_numpy = []

        for i in classes:
            self.class_history.append([])

        class_correct = [0] * len(classes)
        class_incorrect = [0] * len(classes)

        for i in range(len(x_data)):
            x = x_data[i]
            y = y_data[i]

            res = x_result[i]

            actual_label = np.argmax(y)
            pred_label = np.argmax(res)

            if(pred_label == actual_label):
                x_numpy.append(["cor:", str(y), str(res), str(pred_label)])     
                class_correct[actual_label] += 1   
                correct += 1
            else:
                x_numpy.append(["inc:", str(y), str(res), str(pred_label)])
                class_incorrect[actual_label] += 1
                incorrect += 1

        print("\tCorrect: %d" %(correct))
        print("\tIncorrect: %d" %(incorrect))

        for i in range(len(classes)):
            tot = float(class_correct[i] + class_incorrect[i])
            class_acc = -1
            if (tot > 0):
                class_acc = float(class_correct[i]) / tot

            print("\t%s: %.3f" %(classes[i],class_acc)) 

        acc = float(correct) / float(correct + incorrect)  

        print("\tCurrent Network Accuracy: %.3f" %(acc))
```

Then, you are going to want to configure your new callback to your model fit. Assuming your validation data (`val_data`) is some tuple pair, you can use the following:

```
accuracy_callback = AccuracyCallback(val_data)

# you can use the history if desired
history = model.fit( x=_, y=_, verbose=1, 
           epochs=_, shuffle=_, validation_data = val_data,
           callbacks=[accuracy_callback], batch_size=_
         )
```

Please note that the _ indicates values likely to change based on your configuration

Comment: please, what is the purpose for the `self.class_history.append([])` loop? It throws me `AttributeError: 'AccuracyCallback' object has no attribute 'class_history'`, but I before I try to fix it I would like to know what does the piece of code do.

Comment: getting this: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 1):

For **train** per-class accuracy: implement below *on training dataset* - after (and/or before) training on the dataset.

---

For raw per-class *validation* accuracy:

```python
def per_class_accuracy(y_preds,y_true,class_labels):
    return [np.mean([
        (y_true[pred_idx] == np.round(y_pred)) for pred_idx, y_pred in enumerate(y_preds) 
      if y_true[pred_idx] == int(class_label)
                    ]) for class_label in class_labels]

def update_val_history():
    [val_history[class_label].append(np.mean( np.asarray(temp_history).T[class_idx] )
                             ) for class_idx, class_label in enumerate(class_labels)]
```

Example:

```python
class_labels = ['0','1','2','3']
val_history = {class_label:[] for class_label in class_labels}

y_true   = np.asarray([0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3])
y_preds1 = np.asarray([0,3,3,3, 1,1,0,0, 2,2,2,0, 3,3,3,3])
y_preds2 = np.asarray([0,0,3,3, 0,1,0,0, 2,2,2,2, 0,0,0,0])

y_preds1 = model.predict(x1)
temp_hist.append(per_class_accuracy(y_preds1,y_true,class_labels))
update_val_history()
y_preds2 = model.predict(x2)
temp_hist.append(per_class_accuracy(y_preds2,y_true,class_labels))
update_val_history()

print(val_history)
```

**>>{

'0': [0.25, 0.50], 

'1': [0.50, 0.25], 

'2': [0.75, 1.00], 

'3': [1.00, 0.00]  

}**

Answer (score 1):

Update to the solution provided by [Solution by desertnaut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45940876/7631183): 
Now in Keras, you will get an error

> AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute
> 'predict_classes'"

To fix the error use the following code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import numpy as np

Y_test = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1) # Convert one-hot to index
y_pred = np.argmax(model.predict(x_test), axis=-1)
print(classification_report(Y_test, y_pred))
```