# how to show every class accuracy for every epoch in keras

Tags: keras, mnist

I try to train the mnist dataset
when training, I want to show every class accuracy for every epoch not the accuracy for the whole dataset.
What should we do? change the callback()?
Thanks advance!

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45930750/how-to-output-per-class-accuracy-in-keras).

Answer (score 1):

Finally figure it out myself xD
use callback can solve this question
take mnist dataset for example and I wanna show the digit 5 class accuracy here,
do the following:

```python
class TestCallback(Callback):
def __init__(self, test_data):
    self.test_data = test_data

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    x, y = self.test_data
    pred = self.model.predict(x)
    true = y
    prediction = np.argmax(pred,axis=1)
    label = np.argmax(true,axis=1)
    acc = 0
    tar = label[label==5]
    size_of_5 = len(tar)
    print("there are %d of 5"%(size_of_5))
    for i in range(len(label)):
        if label[i]==5:
            if prediction[i]==5:
                 acc += 1/size_of_5
    print('\n digit 5 accuracy:{}\n'.format(acc))
```