# per-class validation accuracy during training

Tags: python, validation, keras, neural-network

Keras gives the overall `training` and `validation` accuracy during training.

[image]

Is there any way to get a `per-class validation accuracy` during training?

**Update:** Error log from Pycharm

```
File "C:/Users/wj96hq/PycharmProjects/PedestrianClassification/Awareness.py", line 82, in <module>
shuffle=True, callbacks=callbacks)
File "C:\Users\wj96hq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\wj96hq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 876, in fit
callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
File "C:\Users\wj96hq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 365, in on_epoch_end
callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
File "C:/Users/wj96hq/PycharmProjects/PedestrianClassification/Awareness.py", line 36, in on_epoch_end
x_test, y_test = self.validation_data[0], self.validation_data[1]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Hey .. you will have to write your custom metric .. you can check this :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37657260/how-to-implement-custom-metric-in-keras

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this to get per class accuracy :

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


class Metrics(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self._data = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        x_test, y_test = self.validation_data[0], self.validation_data[1]
        y_predict = np.asarray(model.predict(x_test))

        true = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)
        pred = np.argmax(y_predict, axis=1)
        
        cm = confusion_matrix(true, pred)
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        self._data.append({
            'classLevelaccuracy':cm.diagonal() ,
        })
        return

    def get_data(self):
        return self._data

metrics = Metrics()
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), callbacks=[metrics])
metrics.get_data()
```

you can make the code change in the metrics class. As you like it ..and this  working . Yuo just use `metrics.get_data()` to get all the info..

Comment: Here the `true` is validation labels and `pred` is the one from the model right? But I still don't understand how does this become per-class validation accuracy during training. This is performed once the training is completed, am I right? Please correct if I have understood wrong.

Comment: you will have to implement something like this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37657260/how-to-implement-custom-metric-in-keras

Comment: Hey @keertikulkarni made some changes ..now it will work

Comment: I have bumped into an issue. So this logic works fine when I train in Google colab. But the same logic leads to an error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` when I tried training in Pycharm. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, i don't use pycharm ...  but in which line do you get the error. Can you show the error log ?

Comment: I have updated the logs in question. And the error exists in  `x_test, y_test = self.validation_data[0], self.validation_data[1]`

Comment: have you checked if the keras / tensorflow version in google colab is same as in your local?

Comment: Yes, the issue was with the version. I had to downgrade the Keras version in my local. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, accuracy is a `global` metric and there's no such thing as `per-class accuracy`. Perhaps you mean `proportion of the class correctly identified`, that's the exact definition of `TPR` or `recall`.

Please refer to answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770376/scikit-learn-get-accuracy-scores-for-each-class), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45930750/how-to-output-per-class-accuracy-in-keras), questions on SO, and this question from [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486609/correct-interpretations-from-confusion-matrix) StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the accuracy for a certain class, or a group of certain classes, masking can be a good solution. See this code:

```
def cus_accuracy(real, pred):

    score = accuracy(real, pred)
    mask = tf.math.greater_equal(real, 5)
    mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=real.dtype)
    score *= mask

    mask2 = tf.math.less_equal(real, 10)
    mask2 = tf.cast(mask2, dtype=real.dtype)
    score *= mask2

return tf.reduce_mean(score)
```

This metric gives you the accuracy for the classes 5 to 10. I used it for measuring the accuracy for certain words in a seq2seq model.